# Writing test class for asynchronous http callout from a trigger

Tags: apex

In a trigger, I have an asynchronous callout method in a class (In this class I have a method to build the json and another method to doing the callout) where I pass the json body string as below:

```
@future(callout=true) //asynchronous callout
public static void sendPayload(String jsonPayload) {
    
    String payload = jsonPayload;
    // send payload
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    // Set the body as a JSON object
    request.setBody(payload);
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    // Parse the JSON response
    if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
        System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    } else {
        System.debug(response.getBody());
        transItemsSent = true;
    } 
}
```

I also have the following class:

```
global with sharing class TransactionHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        response.setBody('{ "keys": { "TransactionID": "00Q0p000001PvhZ" }, '+
            '"values": { "TransactionDate": "2020-01-20" } }');
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then in my test class I have the following:

```
@isTest
private with sharing class TransactionBuildSendJson_Test {
    @isTest
    static void testTransactionCallout() {      // Test sending transaction json
        // Set mock callout class
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TransactionHttpCalloutMock());
        // This causes a fake callout to be sent from the class
        // that implements HttpCalloutMock.

        // Call the method that sends the paylaod
        HttpResponse response = TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload();
        
        // Verify that the responses receive contains the fake values sent
        String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json', 
            'Expected content type is application/json');
        
        String actualValue = response.getBody();
        System.debug('Actual response body = ' + actualValue);

        String expectedValue = '{ "keys": { "TransactionID": "00Q0p000001PvhZ" }, '+
            '"values": { "TransactionDate": "2020-01-20" } }';           

        System.assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue, 
            'Actual and expected json values doesn\'t match');

        System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode(), 
            'Json not sent successfully');  
    }
}
```

While calling the TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload() method and since I am not passing a value, i get the incorrect signature error. If I pass the value I get illegal assignment from void error since the @future sendPayload has to be a void method.

Any ideas on how I can get around this and get the test class to work to get the coverage? I have to http post request to make so I use the same send Payload method by passing in the payload to call it twice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling:

```
Test.stopTest();
```

straight after your `TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload` will ensure that the asynchronous code is run as that [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm) does this

> All
> asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by
> the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are
> run synchronously.

The `TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload` method in real use might need to e.g. do a database update to record its results so your test can assert that data.

Or if you just want to confirm that the call is made, keep a reference to the `TransactionHttpCalloutMock` instance and assert a property of that class set when its `respond` method is called.

You could also add an extra method and call that from your test:

```
@Future(callout=true)
public static void sendPayload(String jsonPayload) {
    synchronousSendPayload(jsonPayload)
}

@TestVisible
private static String synchronousSendPayload(String jsonPayload) {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

but that is obscuring the lack of logic to record the results in the existing method.

Best to write tests with the goal of confirming that the logic is correct; coverage is just an indicator of a lack of test code and is not a sufficient measure in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointer @Keith-c. It helped on my second try :)

I updated it as below:

```
Test.startTest();
TransactionBuildSendJson.sendPayload('testpayload');
Test.stopTest();
```

I also removed the rest of the assert lines. Will still need to figure out on how to do the asserts now.

and the post here helped too: [how to test a future method which makes callouts?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65653/how-to-test-a-future-method-which-makes-callouts).

Hope these helps someone further.